# TabBar items disappear

Tags: view, xamarin.ios, tabbar

In my application I use a TabBar with several items on it. After some time of using the application randomly happens that the items disappear. I use scrollView that is hosted in a main fraim and this view opens several modal dialogs - one of them is fullscreen. I cannot see the reason why the TabBar items disappear. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the tabbar items?  Just curious if the GC might be collecting them if you are not storing them in a C# variable.  This shouldn't be a problem if you're using Interface Builder, though.

Comment: Yes, I create them dynamically. I'll try to store them in a local field.

Comment: Storing into local field did not help. TabBar items still disappear after some longer usage of the App. Please note that I only create these items and I don't later modify them or change or hide them. I only create them and wait for user touch.

Answer (score 0):

Storing them in a "local" field won't help.  You need to store them in a member variable of your class.  There needs to be a reference to your tab bar items somewhere that exists the lifetime of your application to prevent the GC from collecting them.

The reason you wouldn't have to worry about this in WinForms, is you would call Controls.Add()  (or WPF Children.Add()) which adds controls to a C# list internally.  MonoTouch directly calls Objective-C for most things, which isn't GC aware.

Comment: Still did not resolve my problem. I've found out that it is not problem of the items only but the whole tabBar disappear. But it is (probably) not garbage collected but simply not visible for some reason. I set its position in WillRotate method of a page and the reference is not null.